# nrpe unit not found when services try to start on linux server

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel6

Am trying to run nrpe services in linux server but got this error nrpe unit not found.

Please help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with Red Hat 6, so that's what I'm assuming you're running. How did you install NRPE? Is there anything in `/var/log/messages`?

**The following recommendation is for CentOS and Red Hat servers:**

I would recommend using the NRPE package from the EPEL repository. If EPEL isn't already installed, you can run `yum install epel-release`.

Once EPEL is installed, you can then run `yum install nrpe`
Once you do that, your nrpe.cfg file will be located in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`, and you should be able to then enable and (re)start the nrpe service with: `chkconfig nrpe on` (which will ensure NRPE starts on system boot), and `/etc/init.d/nrpe restart` (to restart the service).